# How to restrict the view for particular user when they are login in using cookie name using php

Tags: php, cookies, login-control

This is my php code

```
<?php
require_once('../includes/config.php');
// include file to check, If current user loggedin or not
include('log-security.php');
require_once('../cs/includes/header.php');
if(in_array(cms_username, $allowedUsers))
{
    $allowedUsers=['john', 'akhil'];
    <div id="view8"></div>
}


?>
This is my div id code
<div id="view8" class="tabcontents">
<h3>Creation of  files</h3>
</div>
```

Im new to PHP, Please help me to correct the code if its wrong .
while login only it should restrict the user.when allowed user is entered then the viewid should displayed for others it should not.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that :

```
<?php

require_once('../includes/config.php');
require_once('../cs/includes/header.php');

include('log-security.php');
$allowedUsers = array('john', 'akhil');

?>


<?php if (in_array('cms_username', $allowedUsers)): ?>
  <div id="view8" class="tabcontents">
    <h3>Creation of  files</h3>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Hi @Dr Z Im able to view Creation of files If I login using other users also.

Comment: How can you retrieve the "cms_username" ?

Comment: its a cookie name from header.php file